Hazelcast configuration for AWS works with lib 5.0 but fails with 5.1.7
I'm having a problem with getting my app to connect to hazelcast cluster in AWS (community edition).
I've tried quite a few things in the configuration below, different environment variables passed to the JVM as recommended by another hazelcast log message (for java 9+) etc but every single time I was getting the "Couldn't connect to the service, [2] retrying in 2 seconds..." like message logged by com.hazelcast.spi.utils.RetryUtils. What eventually helped was downgrading the hazelcast library from 5.1.7 (the one that comes as default with SpringBoot 2.7.18) to 5.0 and then it finally connected to the cluster and displayed its members.
The 5.0 library though has quite a few security vulnerabilities logged against it, so I'd really like to use at least the one that comes with the SpringBoot 2.7.18.
Have there been any new changes that need to be applied to the hazelcast config when in AWS environment introduced somewhere between version 5.0 and 5.1.7 of the library?
Could not find any migration guides from 5.0 to anything higher than that.
Will appreciate any suggestions.
Below is the programmatic config that I use:
    @Bean
    @Profile("aws")
    public Config hazelcastConfigAws(ProfileSupport profileSupport) {

        final Config config = new Config();
        getMapConfigs().forEach(config::addMapConfig);
        config.setProperty("hazelcast.jmx", "true");

        config.getNetworkConfig().getJoin().getAwsConfig().setEnabled(true)
            .setProperty("tag-key", "Role,Environment")
            .setProperty("tag-value", "my-app," + profileSupport.findEnvironmentProfile());

        return config;
    }

    private List<MapConfig> getMapConfigs() {
        return List.of(
            new MapConfig(DEFAULT_NAME_EVENT_STORE_MAP).setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT)
                .setBackupCount(1)
                .setMergePolicyConfig(new MergePolicyConfig(PutIfAbsentMergePolicy.class.getName(), 100)),
            new MapConfig(DEFAULT_NAME_SENT_NOTIFICATIONS_MAP)
                .setInMemoryFormat(InMemoryFormat.OBJECT)
                .setBackupCount(1)
                .setEvictionConfig(
                    new EvictionConfig().setEvictionPolicy(EvictionPolicy.LRU).setMaxSizePolicy(MaxSizePolicy.PER_NODE))
                .setMergePolicyConfig(new MergePolicyConfig(PutIfAbsentMergePolicy.class.getName(), 100))
        );
    }


